# jQuery: newline in textarea placeholder doesn't work for Mozilla Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, textarea, placeholder

This is my HTML code:

```
<textarea class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all note-text-area" id="backlinks" rows="10" name="backlinks" placeholder="Referring URL;;Link URL;;Anchor Text" style='width:100%'></textarea>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$('[name=backlinks]').attr('placeholder', 'Referring URL;;Link URL;;Anchor Text\nor\nURL');
```

Altough it works well when using the Chrome browser (it shows the line breaks in the textarea placeholder), this is what I get on Mozilla Firefox:

> Referring URL;;Link URL;;Anchor TextorURL

So, I really wonder what wrong is and how I can display newlines inside textarea placeholder when using Mozilla Firefox. Any idea?

Comment: Can not reproduce. Tested in Firefox. Works as expected.

Comment: Do you mean it shows the textarea placeholder content as follows?

Comment: No, in Firefox it shows as expected, with two returns, one after `Text` and the other after `or`, so the placeholder has 3 lines.

Comment: Then, why doesn't it show me the same output on Firefox?! Is it a question of browser version?

Comment: But i tested it in FIrefox! What are you asking then?

Comment: May I ask what version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: The version is Quantum 60.0.1